# Solutions of this integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}dz=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I must integrate the function 
$f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}$ long the circle  $\gamma$ of radius $r=1/4 $ and center in the origin.
I thing that 
$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}dz=0$, because $lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=1$.

Is this solution correct?

Other solutions are very appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

The only zero of the denominator of $f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}$ for $|z|\le 1/4$ is at the origin.  We can expand the numerator as

$$\begin{align}
e^{z^2}-1&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{n!}\\\\
&=z^2\left(1+\frac12z^2+O(z^4)\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

while we can expand the denominator as

$$\begin{align}
z\sin(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\,z^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\\\\
&=z^2\left(1-\frac16z^2+O(z^4)\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that for $z\ne 0$

$$\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}=1+\frac23z^2+O(z^4)$$

So, $f(z)$ has a removable discontinuity and is analytic for $|z|\le 1/4$.  Therefore, from [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem),

$$\oint_{|z|=1/4}\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z\sin(z)}\,dz=0$$